# Trying to make dropdown item a link using html, css, and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I am very very new to JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and programming in general. I've done some stuff on Codecademy but I feel like the best way for me to learn would be to do a project for myself. I decided to make a catalogue of all my games/comics/books/etc.

So I found a tutorial on YouTube about creating a dropdown menu, and I've done that and it works, however, I don't know how to make the options in the dropdown a link. I'm sure this is very simple but couldn't find anything online to answer my question.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/999watch.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <ul class="menu-ctn">
          <li>HOME</li>
          <li id="menu">
            SYSTEMS
            <ul Id="dropdown">
              <li>Ps1</li>
              <li>Ps2</li>
              <li>Ps3</li>
              <li>Ps4</li>
              <li>GCN</li>
              <li>Wii</li>
              <li>Switch</li>
              <li>GBA</li>
              <li>DS</li>
              <li>3DS</li>
              <li>PSP</li>
              <li>Vita</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>BOOKS</li>
          <li>COMICS</li>
      </ul>
  </nav>  
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.logo {
    width: 10%;
}


.logo img {
    width: 50%;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu-ctn > li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(158, 155, 155);
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-ctn li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    top: 100%;
}

#dropdown li {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#dropdown.active {
    display: block;

}
```

here is my JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);

function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
    
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if the code for the links should be in the html or the JavaScript. I don't THINK it goes in the css code, but at this point I don't even know. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea - best way to learn is always to start doing!

So yeah, you’re right that the CSS doesn’t have anything to do with the items in the dropdowns being links. Depending on what type of link you want/need, you could look at this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

If you want to make your items *look* like links, you could do this in css by checking out the :hover selector so that when the cursor moves over the items in the list, they change appearance to make it more obvious to the user it’s a link!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap text inside `dropdown` with `<a>` tag (anchor element) and specify where you need to link in `href` attribute, it could be an external URL on relative path:

```html
<li><a href="http://link-some-where.com">Ps1</a></li>
<li><a href="/about-me.html">Ps2</a></li>
<li><a href="/another-page">Ps3</a></li>
```

More reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)